# Why my entire div is clickable instead of just only link?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <span> Test text </span>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 align-self-center text-md-right ng-scope">This is a link 
    </a>
</div>
```

I checked that and noticed that my `<a>` tag is clickable in the whole div, but I totally don't understand why. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the codeply: https://www.codeply.com/p/UieZQL1mHw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your `a` tag on `div` like:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <span> Test text </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 align-self-center text-md-right ng-scope">
           <a href="#" class="">This is a link 
           </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <a href="http://example.com">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <span> Test text </span>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 align-self-center text-md-right ng-scope">This is a link </a>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Use this. Full div will clickable.